# Salesforce CPQ schedule dates can not be sold again

Tags: calendar, cpq, schedule, steelbrick

I am trying to create a service in salesforce CPQ selling a service that can only be sold on dates that have not be scheduled before.

The use case is: Once a date has been scheduled with a set date or date range this date range is no longer able to be sold. Ideally it would be great if a calendar would display with the unavailable dates greyed out.

You will see in the image below that all of the dates in the month are currently a dark blue. What I am trying to accomplish is when the date is unavailable to show in the lite grey ie 26,27,28,29,30 in the first line.

[image]
Currently what I am using to solve this is a price rule that throws an error whenever a date is selected that is unavailable. This is not the most user friendly way for the sales team because its "enter a date and cross your fingers that it is a date that can be scheduled".

Comment: @Adrian Larson I have tried creating a new field on the quote line editor to enter in a start and stop date which gets added to the quote. I am not sure how to create a rule or workflow that will look at all of the dates that are currently on completed orders to throw an error when that date for a "product" is selected once it has already been booked.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post with any clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, this is a custom vf component.  I would create a vf component to do just this and include it in the detail page of the quote.